# Carousel pictures are below each other, I'd like them inside with a slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My carousel is showing each slide below each other instead of one.

I have 3 slides that are below each other, instead I want them to be "inside" with a slide, but for some reason it doesn't work.

A snippet is below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 1000
 })
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".carousel-inner div:first").addClass("active");
 });
 </script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="1">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="2">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share a jsfiddle example to help the community easily troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/a2bpqq2h/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/"></script> dunno how to embed it

Comment: Are you sure you're linking to the correct JavaScript files?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Thats what i have linked in my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div containing the images shoud have class="item" not "carousel-item", change it.

Here's the working snippet.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval:2000
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="2">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game. The prev post got it. :)
The div container classes holding the images were using a different class. This line of JS isn't necessary because the class can be included in the HTML.
`$(".carousel-inner div:first").addClass("active");`
The extra CSS is just for the example.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 1000
    })
    // Not needed because the class can be included in the HTML
    // $(".carousel-inner div:first").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="1">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="2">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://veterans4you.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/landscape-7-800x400.jpg" alt="3">
      <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```